# Where does the force that resists changes to an objects geodesic path in empty space come from?

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics

assuming an object is free of a gravitational field and following its geodesic. Applying a force would be changing the 4 vector momentum of the object relative to the frame the object was in before the force. What is pushing back on the force to resist that change? The object's relative time will change and relative energy. Can the force pushing back be thought of as a pressure exerted by changing the object relative time in addition to changing relative kinetic energy? The object has mass and the mass is affecting spacetime locally, can the resistance be thought of as some kind of stiffness or resistance to change in the local spacetime?

Comment: I am not sure the question makes sense -- are you asking what happens to the resisting force when someone pushes a ball in flat spacetime? And what do you mean by the relative time and relative energy?

Answer (score 1):

> What is pushing back on the force to resist that change ?

Nothing. An external force acting on an object can only change the object's momentum at a certain rate. If this were not so then any external force, no matter how small, would instantly accelerate that object to the speed of light.

Comment: How about an object that is large like an asteroid? It has inertia that resists change and pushes back again a force that is trying to change its geodesic

Comment: @bigbalddoc I think you are confusing inertia - a consequence of Newton's Second Law - with Newton's Third Law ("for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction"). Inertia is required to prevent accelerations being infinite; Newton's Third Law is required to conserve momentum.

Comment: the clocks on the the object will slow down and the kinetic energy will increase after the force relative to the inertial frame it was in before the force. so the spacetime for that object has now changed. Was it the changing of the spacetime that caused the inertia or resistance to change when it was pushed?

Comment: "the clocks on the the object will slow down ... the spacetime for that object has now changed" - sorry, but that's just nonsense. You appear to be stringing random physics concepts and terms together without understanding what they mean. I am done here.